# If statement always prints (Python)

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying to add an if statement to check for invalid input.  It's working like it should and looping back again if the user enters "Yes" and ending if the user enters "No".  But for some odd reason no matter what the answer: yes, no, random character, etc.  It always prints the "invalid input" statement.  I'm trying to make that only print when the answer isn't "Yes" or "No".

```
while cont == "Yes":
    word=input("Please enter the word you would like to scan for. ") #Asks for word
    capitalized= word.capitalize()  
    lowercase= word.lower()
    accumulator = 0

    print ("\n")
    print ("\n")        #making it pretty
    print ("Searching...")

    fileScan= open(fileName, 'r')  #Opens file

    for line in fileScan.read().split():   #reads a line of the file and stores
        line=line.rstrip("\n")
        if line == capitalized or line == lowercase:
            accumulator += 1
    fileScan.close

    print ("The word", word, "is in the file", accumulator, "times.")

    cont = input ('Type "Yes" to check for another word or \
"No" to quit. ')  #deciding next step
    cont = cont.capitalize()

    if cont != "No" or cont != "Yes":
        print ("Invalid input!")

print ("Thanks for using How Many!")  #ending
```

Answer (score 8):

That's because whatever you enter, at least *one* of the tests is True:

```
>>> cont = 'No'
>>> cont != "No" or cont != "Yes"
True
>>> (cont != "No", cont != "Yes")
(False, True)
>>> cont = 'Yes'
>>> cont != "No" or cont != "Yes"
True
>>> (cont != "No", cont != "Yes")
(True, False)
```

Use `and` instead:

```
>>> cont != 'No' and cont != 'Yes'
False
>>> cont = 'Foo'
>>> cont != 'No' and cont != 'Yes'
True
```

or use a membership test (`in`):

```
>>> cont not in {'Yes', 'No'}  # test against a set of possible values
True
```

Answer (score 2):

`if cont != "No" or cont != "Yes":`

Both `Yes` and `No` sastisfy this condition

It should be `cont != "No" and cont != "Yes"`

Answer (score 2):

Cont will always either not equal "No" or not equal "Yes". You want `and` instead of `or`.

Or, alternately,

```
if cont not in ['No', 'Yes']:
```

which will be more extensible if you want to, e.g., add lowercase.

Answer (score 2):

`if cont != "No" or cont != "Yes"` means "if the answer is not No or it is not Yes".  Everything is either not No or not Yes, since it can't be both.

Change it instead to `if cont not in ("Yes", "No")`.

Answer (score 2):

You need an `and` operation instead of `or`. Using *or* operation, your condition will evaluate to true no matter what the input value is. Change the condition to:

```
if cont != "No" and cont != "Yes":
```

or simply use:

```
if cont not in ("No", "Yes"):
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if cont != "No" or cont != "Yes":
```

What could you possibly input that would not satisfy this?